# c# string delimiter

Tags: c#-4.0

I have string value like this:

```
string strRole = "ab=Admin,ca=system,ou=application,role=branduk|ab=Manager,ca=system,ou=application,role=brankdusa|ab=sale,ca=system,ou=application,role=brandAu";
```

I just need to retrieve role to string array. I wonder if there is the best way to split the string in C# 4.0

```
string[] arrStrRole = strRole.Split('|').Select .. ??
```

Basically, I need  brandUK, brandUsa, brandAu to  string[] arrStrRole.
Thanks.

Comment: Best for what? Speed? Readability? Memory usage? Something else? "Best" doesn't mean much without context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string[] arrStrRole = strRole.Split('|').Select(r => r.Split(new []{"role="}, StringSplitOptions.None)[1]).ToArray()
```

results in an string array with three strings:

> branduk
>   brankdusa
>   brandAu

Answer (score 0):

you can use `string[] arrStrRole = strRole.Split('|',',');`  and this will split according to  | and , characters

Answer (score 0):

You could use an extension like this which would allow you to test it easily.

```
 public static string[] ParseRolesIntoList(this string csvGiven)
            {
                var list = new List<string>();
                if (csvGiven == null) return null;
                var csv = csvGiven.Split(',');
                foreach (var s in csv)
                {
                    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) continue;
                    if(!s.StartsWith("role")) continue;
                    var upperBound =  s.IndexOf("|");
                    if (upperBound <= 0) upperBound = s.Length;
                    var role = s.Substring(s.IndexOf("=") + 1, 
                                        upperBound - s.IndexOf("=") - 1);
                    list.Add(role);
                }
                return list.ToArray();
            }
```

Test below found brankdusa typo in your example.  Some of the other answers would not deal with brandAu as it matches slightly differently.  Try running this test against them if you like

```
  [Test]
    public void Should_parse_into_roles()
    {
        //GIVEN 
        const string strRole = "ab=Admin,ca=system,ou=application,role=branduk|ab=Manager,ca=system,ou=application,role=brankdusa|ab=sale,ca=system,ou=application,role=brandAu";

        //WHEN
        var roles = strRole.ParseRolesIntoList();

        //THEN
        Assert.That(roles.Length, Is.EqualTo(3));
        Assert.That(roles[0], Is.EqualTo("branduk"));
        Assert.That(roles[1], Is.EqualTo("brankdusa"));
        Assert.That(roles[2], Is.EqualTo("brandAu"));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Split` in this `LINQ` query:

```
var roles = from token in strRole.Split('|')
            from part in token.Split(',')
            where part.Split('=')[0] == "role"
            select part.Split('=')[1];
```

Note that this is yet prone to error and requires the data always to have this format. I mention it because you've started with `Split('|').Select...`. You can also use nested loops.

If you need it as `String[]` you just need to call `ToArray`:

```
String[] result = roles.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `Regex` rather than splitting string. In combination with your intended `Select` solution, it could look like this:

```
var roles = Regex.Matches(strRole, @"role=(\w+)")
                 .Cast<Match>()
                 .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value).ToArray();
```

Comment: Should probably be `Groups[1]` instead of `Groups[0]`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't try it.. Updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This gives an array of the 3 values.

```
void Main()
{
  string strRole = "ab=Admin,ca=system,ou=application,role=branduk|ab=Manager,ca=system,ou=application,role=brankdusa|ab=sale,ca=system,ou=application,role=brandAu";

  var arrStrRole = strRole.Split('|',',')
                     .Where(a => a.Split('=')[0] == "role")
                     .Select(b => b.Split('=')[1]);

  arrStrRole.Dump();
}
```